# How does ruby gem works in a rails environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am trying to understand in `rails`, how `ruby gems` become available to used automatically without being `required` in the files that are using the gems?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is done through `bundler/setup`: http://bundler.io/v1.3/bundler_setup.html. It is required inside your `config/boot.rb` file. In short it firstly sets environmental variable to point to your Gemfile:

```
ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] ||= File.expand_path('../../Gemfile', __FILE__)
```

Then it adds paths for all your gems to LOAD_PATH, by requiring `bundler/setup`:

```
require 'bundler/setup' if File.exist?(ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'])
```

Then it requires all the needed gems (config/application.rb):

```
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)
```

Answer (score 4):

Rails applications use bundler (that's the thing using the `Gemfile`). When bundler loads the `Gemfile` on startup of a rails application, it automatically requires all gems listed there, thus you don't have to do this yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I recomend you to read ["Crafting Rails 4 Applications: Expert Practices for Everyday Rails Development"](https://pragprog.com/book/jvrails2/crafting-rails-4-applications) 
Chapter 1. Creating Our Own Renderer:

> Notice the gem has the same name as the file inside the lib directory, which
>   is pdf_renderer . By following this convention, whenever you declare this gem in
>   a Rails application’s Gemfile , the file at lib/pdf_renderer.rb will be automatically
>   required.